# How do I calculate my modifiers

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I don't know how to calculate my modifiers, my ability scores are:

| Ability | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Strength | 15 |
| Dexterity | 17 |
| Constitution | 13 |
| Intelligence | 21 |
| Wisdom | 15 |
| Charisma | 18 |

I am playing Dungeons and Dragons 3.5 edition.

Comment: Which modifiers are you talking about? The basic modifiers from ability scores are included near the front of the PHB; do you mean those, or something else?

Comment: Just because its an easy question doesn't make it invalid...

Comment: @Ifusaso That's right. Hold votes are for when there's a problem with the question that means it can't be answered here. If it's just a question that can be answered easily by reading the rules, that's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 3):

Odd numbers don't bump you up modifiers, so you + goes up one for each even number above 10:

- 15: +2 (same as 14) STR/WIS
- 17: +3 (same as 16) DEX
- 13: +1 (same as 12) CON
- 21: +5 (same as 20) INT
- 18: +4              CHA

[This is the d20SRD page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#abilityModifiers) you would find that on.

Also, those numbers seem exorbitantly high, you may want to check with your GM if you calculated them correctly,

Comment: I added my race modifiers into my rolls